# 3 DIVs, need 2 next to each other (l to r) & 3rd div is pushed down too far on web page?

Tags: html

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS, and I have seem to hit a wall. I have three divs within one section id of the home page. If you look on the "About" page, you will see some additional text, "test" (this is the third div).

"test" should be on the home page, not the "about" page. For some reason it is too far down. Once I get it in position I will replace with a few lines of text.

"test" should be on the right side of the home page, next to the word "blue".

Here is a link to my code via code pen: http://cdpn.io/EqnyI

Answer (score 0):

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrLHQ/)

Sorry for not codepen.

First is moving from about page to home. Its easy html changing element node. You can see it on demo.

Second is "test" right side. I uncomment your `padding-top: 50px;` end replace

```
/* 
*  text-align: center;
*  to
*/
   text-align: right;
```

Comment: Thank you! Using float: right, works better. text align pushes the text on the left hand side down. Thank you again